# Filter get_categories() for taxonomy term in WordPress

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, filters

I want to show a category only if a (custom) post is in that category AND region = $name for that post.

So, e.g. I have a custom post (type "business") named "Mamma Mia" in child-category: "pizzerias" (and in parent-category "food"), and in region "Rotterdam" (custom taxonomy: "region", custom taxonomy term: "rotterdam").

=> display category "pizzerias" (and parent-category "food")

Only, I have no clue how to accomplish this. I'd appreciate any help on this puzzle.

```
<?php 

// $filter = array('region'=>$name); 

$categories = get_categories(); 
foreach ($categories as $cat) 
{ 
    if($cat->parent < 1) 
    { 
    $cat_name = $cat->cat_name; 
    $catid = get_cat_ID( $cat_name ); 
    echo $cat_name. '<br/>'; 

    $args=array( 
      'orderby' => 'name', 
      'order' => 'ASC', 
      'child_of' => $catid 
      ); 
    $categories=get_categories($args); 
      foreach($categories as $category) {  
        echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a><br/>'; 
        }  

    } 
} 

// print_r($categories);  


?>
```

Comment: So you want to list category `terms` that have `business` es assigned which are also assigned specific `region`?

Comment: @Henk, can you explain a little further *where* you'd like to do this? On a single post page? On a taxonomy archive? On a category archive?

Comment: I think we can generalize this to faceted search. There is [a plugin with this name](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/faceted-search/), but it seems you can't combine multiple taxonomies. Because this is so interesting, I added the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

> the intention is to show a list of
>   categories, but only those categories
>   that have posts where the custom
>   taxonomy region is set to Rotterdam

This is done in the [Query Multiple Taxonomies](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/) plugin:

http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/query-multiple-taxonomies/trunk/core.php?rev=308185#L10

Comment: And more specifically, in its [drill-down navigation widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/screenshots/). Great! Now this only should be extended to show the parent categories too: if a post is attached to `Pizzerias` I also see it when I browse `Food`, but `Food` is not shown in the widget if the post is not explicitly attached to it.

Answer (score 1):

General idea - query for specific set of posts, gather all of their categories, filter, let function beat them in shape.

Generic code:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'tag' => 'linux'
));

$categories = array();

foreach( $posts as $post ) {

    $cats = get_the_category($post->ID);

    foreach($cats as $c)
        $categories[] = $c->term_id;
}

$categories = array_unique($categories);
sort($categories);
$categories = implode(',', $categories);

$result = get_categories(array(
    'include' => $categories
));
```

Issues are - as I remember decent queries for multiple taxonomies will only come in WP 3.1 and this might get very intensive so will take caching (probably for each `region`).

Comment: How does the `include` parameter affect hierarchical results? If there are some posts in `Pizzerias`, but none directly attached to its parent `Food`, will `Food` be displayed? Or are posts automatically attached to parent categories too?

Comment: @Jan Fabry tested, if only child category id is passed to `get_categories()` then parent category is not retrieved. :( So one more step would be to loop through categories and get parents. Even larger mess.

Comment: I think we should look in the direction of a custom SQL query, joining multiple taxonomy tables. And caching, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

On the version of wordpress I'm using which is version 3.1.2. If you were to add 'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_term' to the array of args it should work. So here's a modification to your original code to include the taxonomy in the array. Don't know the taxonomy name you're trying to use or not though:

```
<?php 

// $filter = array('region'=>$name); 

$categories = get_categories(); 
foreach ($categories as $cat) 
{ 
    if($cat->parent < 1) 
    { 
    $cat_name = $cat->cat_name; 
    $catid = get_cat_ID( $cat_name ); 
    echo $cat_name. '<br/>'; 

    $args=array( 
      'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_term', 
      'orderby' => 'name', 
      'order' => 'ASC', 
      'child_of' => $catid 
      ); 
    $categories=get_categories($args); 
      foreach($categories as $category) {  
        echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a><br/>'; 
        }  

    } 
} 

// print_r($categories);  
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've adapted @rarst's answer from above to use 3 custom taxonomies.  I only want to spit out the terms that are attached to one or more of the posts in the loop.

Here's my function that I've added to functions.php:

```
function dv_setup_sidebar_cats() {
    global $wp_query;

    $designers = array();
    $sizes     = array();
    $colors    = array();

    foreach( $wp_query->posts as $post ) {

        $des   = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'designer');
        $siz   = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'size');
        $col   = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'color');    

        foreach($des as $d) {
            $designers[] = $d->term_id;
        }

        foreach($siz as $s) {
            $sizes[] = $s->term_id;
        }

        foreach($col as $c) {
            $colors[] = $c->term_id;
        }

    }

    if ( !empty($designers) ) {
        $designers = array_unique($designers);
        sort($designers);
        $designers = implode(',', $designers);

        $dresult   = get_categories(array(
            'include'  => $designers,
            'taxonomy' => 'designer'
        ));
    }

    if ( !empty($sizes) ) {
        $sizes = array_unique($sizes);
        sort($sizes);
        $sizes = implode(',', $sizes);

        $sresult   = get_categories(array(
            'include'  => $sizes,
            'taxonomy' => 'size'
        ));
    } 

    if ( !empty($colors) ) {
        $colors = array_unique($colors);
        sort($colors);
        $colors = implode(',', $colors);

        $cresult   = get_categories(array(
            'include'  => $colors,
            'taxonomy' => 'color'
        ));
    }

    $return = array(
        'size'     => $sresult,
        'color'    => $cresult,
        'designer' => $dresult
    );


    return $return;

}
```

Hope this helps someone else.

-J

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I've missed something, but would it not be as simple as;

```
if (is_object_in_term($post->ID, 'region', 'rotterdam'))
    the_category(); // displays categories associated with current post
```

In the admin, are you attaching the post to both 'pizzerias' and 'food' (by ticking both checkboxes), or just 'pizzerias'?

If the latter, `the_category()` won't show 'Food' by default, so you'll have to grab the category hierarchy yourself.

Comment: No, the intention is to show a list of categories, but only those categories that have posts where the custom taxonomy `region` is set to `Rotterdam`. This question was [also asked on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312530/filter-get-categories-for-taxonomy-term-in-wordpress), by the way.

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding this seems like a fitting answer. If `Mamma Mia` is `pizzeria` in `rotterdam` then by definition there **are** pizzerias in rotterdam and category should be displayed. Otherwise I don't understand how category is supposed to be connected to region.

Comment: @Rarst: The way I understood the question is that the category list should not be shown just on a post page, but for example on `region/rotterdam/`: for all posts that use this custom taxonomy term, give me one tree of all categories they are attached too. The OP uses `get_categories()`, which is not limited to the categories of the current post.

Answer (score 0):

you can return the taxonomie for custom post with a small funtion:

```
    function get_the_taxonomy( $taxonomy, $id = FALSE ) {
        global $post;

        $id = (int) $id;
        if ( !$id )
            $id = (int) $post->ID;

        $categories = get_object_term_cache( $id, $taxonomy );
        if ( FALSE === $categories ) {
            $categories = wp_get_object_terms( $id, $taxonomy );
            wp_cache_add($id, $categories, $taxonomy . '_relationships');
        }

        if ( !empty( $categories ) )
            usort( $categories, '_usort_terms_by_name' );
        else
            $categories = array();

        foreach ( (array) array_keys( $categories ) as $key ) {
            _make_cat_compat( $categories[$key] );
        }

        return $categories;
    }
```

Also you can use the function of wp-core:

```
$taxonomys = get_the_term_list($id, YOUR_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE, '', ', ', '' );
```

and you can ask for tax with `is_tax()`, see [codex for this conditional tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax)

Maybe this helps, when i understand your problem right. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I think Henk Jan wants to get a list of categories, independent from a current post. Just all categories that have posts in them assigned to the custom term `rotterdam`.

Comment: Thanks for hint; i think it possible to use a custom query with the custom term. The post give back all terms, and the query must use all or the first term to list in the loop all post to this term. Also it is possible to return all categories to the posts in thuis query.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helping me out - that's really great. I'd like to share with you what I've come up with. I know it is not the smartest solution. The drawback is that a parent category is shown for a region, when there is no custom post attached to it for this region (but there is a custom post attached to it for an other region).

I am using this on a region (taxonomy archive) page.

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories();
foreach ($categories as $cat)
{
    if($cat->parent < 1)
    {
        $cat_name = $cat->cat_name;                         
        $catid = get_cat_ID( $cat_name );

        echo '<div class="indexcolumn-top">';

        $img = $taxonomy_images_plugin->get_image_html( 'fullsize', $cat->term_taxonomy_id );
        if( !empty( $img ) )
            print $img;
        else 
            echo '<h2>' .$cat_name. '</h2>';

        $input = array();
        $args=array(
          'child_of' => $catid,
          'orderby' => 'name',
          'order' => 'ASC'
          );

        $categories = get_categories($args);
        foreach ($categories as $cat)
        {
            $cat_name = $cat->cat_name;
            $catid = get_cat_ID( $cat_name );

            $args = array(
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'taxonomy_name' => 'region',
                'taxonomy_term' => $name,
            );
            $custom_posts = get_posts_by_taxonomy($args);
            if ($custom_posts):
                foreach ($custom_posts as $post):
                    setup_postdata($post);
                    $postcategory = get_the_category(); $postcat = $postcategory[0]->cat_name;
                    if ($postcat == $cat_name):
                        $category = get_the_category(); 
                        $input[] = $catid;
                    endif;
                endforeach;
            endif;
        }
        echo '<br/>';
        $output = array_unique($input);
        if (empty($output)):
            echo '<p>Geen bedrijven</p>';
            echo '</div>';
        else :
            echo '<ul class="port-box">';
            foreach ($output as $output) {
                $cat_name = get_cat_name($output);  
                echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link($output) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $cat_name ) . '" ' . '>' . $cat_name .'</a></li>';                             
            }
            echo '</ul></div>';
        endif;
    }                                                   
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't think this is an efficient way to do it: you do a lot of queries, and I don't understand the inner post loop: if a post is found in the current category, you can probably just add that category to the list without looping through all the posts?

Comment: @Jan: I know it is not the smartest solution. I don't understand your remark about the inner post loop though. You'll need the inner post loop to find a match - or not. Or, can you quit the loop in case of hit? But, how would you do that then?

Comment: Nevermind, I thought your `get_posts_by_taxonomy()` function selected both by taxonomy and category. The following question is why you repeat this query over and over, instead of doing it once and re-using the results. And why check only the first category? If a business is in both `Pizzeria` and `French Fries`, only one of them will be returned, so you possible miss one in the end.

Comment: @Jan: OK. I am only checking the first category because my businesses can be in one category only. I don't get your first question. The if ($custom_posts): endif; can be dropped. But, you'll need to loop to find a match - or not. What do you mean with reusing?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $cat_id = $_GET["cat"];?>     
      <li id="category-active"><a><?php if ($cat_id){echo get_the_category_by_id($li_id);}else{ echo "Selectedcategory";}?></a></li>            <?php   $subcategories1 = wp_list_categories("title_li&child_of=$cat_id&hide_empty");
                wp_list_categories("title_li=&current_category="); ?>
                    </ul><?php ?>
```

thanks for your help.

but i think their is no need of foreach or any loop we can get child of any category by using this simple code first `$li_id` get the current cat id and we dynamicaly passed this id to `child_of=$cat_id` and it show the selected cat childs i am using it in my site side  bar.