# Filter get_cat_id for Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I have this simple snippet to retrieve the categories (taxonomies) of my Custom Post Type 'portfolio' I need to display each taxonomy but it displays all the categories.

I just saw this question [Filter get_categories() for taxonomy term in WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4724/filter-get-categories-for-taxonomy-term-in-wordpress) and unfortunately I tried with no success.

```
<?php
    query_posts("post_type=portfolio");
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    $catid = get_cat_id('Images');
?>

<?php 
    $categories=  get_categories('child_of='.$catid.'&orderby=name'); 
    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
    $input = '<li><a href="#" data-value="category-'.$cat->category_nicename.'">';
      $input .= $cat->cat_name;
      $input .= '</a></li>';
      echo $input;
      }
?>
```

Can you please guide me or give me a hint? Thanks so much.

Comment: _categories (taxonomies)_ Category is taxonomy but other taxonomies are not categories. Could you please explain better what exactly you want to retrieve? Terms from several taxonomies?

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what type of data/use-case you are working with? Like @Rarst I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sure let me explain better. I have a Custom Post Type in my custom post type I've created a Custom Taxonomy called 'Portfolio' with 1 category called 'Work' (parent) with 3 childs (Images, Video Production, Web Design). I want to display the Name of the child categories into a list. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are mixing up terminology a bit. Portfolio is `taxonomy`, but Work, Images, etc are `terms` (not `categories`).

So you need to adjust functions for your taxonomy. Try this:

Replace:

```
$catid = get_cat_id('Images');
```

Becomes:

```
$catid = get_term_by( 'name', 'Images', 'portfolio' );
$catid = $catid->term_id;
```

And:

```
$categories = get_categories('child_of='.$catid.'&orderby=name');
```

Becomes:

```
$categories = get_categories('child_of='.$catid.'&orderby=name&taxonomy=portfolio');
```